# R - Convert matrix to vector from the bottom and row wise

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have the following matrix:

```
m <- matrix(1:9, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
```

that I need to flatten, i.e., convert to a vector.

However, instead of going along the columns:

```
as.vector(m)
[1] 7 4 1 8 5 2 9 6 3
```

I need the resulting vector to go along the rows and from the bottom and to the right, e.g.:

```
[1] 7 8 9 4 5 6 1 2 3
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use the following ways:

- **Solution 1**:

  ```
  as.vector(t(apply(m, 2, rev)))
  ```

  which gives:

  ```
  > as.vector(t(apply(m, 2, rev)))
  [1] 7 8 9 4 5 6 1 2 3
  ```
- **Solution 2**:

  ```
  unlist(rev(data.frame(t(m))),use.names = F)
  ```

  which gives:

  ```
  > unlist(rev(data.frame(t(m))),use.names = F)
  [1] 7 8 9 4 5 6 1 2 3
  ```

Comment: Thanks, both solutions work and #2 seems to be the fastest one.

Comment: Yes, `apply()` in Solution 1 maybe the bottleneck when with large matrix

Answer (score 6):

**1)** Reverse the first dimension, tranpose and then unravel:

```
c(t(m[nrow(m):1, ]))
## [1] 7 8 9 4 5 6 1 2 3
```

**2)** Here is a second approach which computes the indices and then applies them. It is longer but avoids the transpose:

```
nr <- nrow(m)
nc <- ncol(m)
c(m[cbind(rep(nr:1, each = nc), 1:nc)])
## [1] 7 8 9 4 5 6 1 2 3
```

**2a)** A variation of (2) is to use a 1d index:

```
m[rep(nr:1, each = nc) + nr * (0:(nc - 1))]
## [1] 7 8 9 4 5 6 1 2 3
```

### Note

I tried it for a 100x100 and a 1000x1000 matrix.  In the first case (1) was the fastest and in the second case (2) and (2a) were the fastest thus if speed is a concern the actual dimensions seem to make a difference as to which to choose.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be also using `asplit()`:

```
unlist(rev(asplit(m, 1)))

[1] 7 8 9 4 5 6 1 2 3
```